# Yii2 mongodb: how to change database?

Tags: yii2

My application use many databases, they are in same structure, but data has no relation between different databases. I need to change database via request params. 
In the config can only setup dsn, but I want to change database dynamically.
How can I do that.

Comment: I use yii2-mongodb extension component. And in Yii 1.1 I use yii-mongo extension, can use Yii::app()->mongodb->setDB(foo); to do that. In Yii2, I don't know how to do.

Answer (score 0):

I got myself:

```
$mongo = Yii::$app->get('mongodb');
$mongo->options['db'] = 'foo';
```

Comment: That only works the first time. As soon as you execute the first query it will actually open the connection to that specific database and it will remain like that unless you `close()` it again and modify the db.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to defined multiple connections in the configuration:

```
'components' =>
[
    ...
    'mongodb' =>
    [
        'class'     => '\yii\mongodb\Connection',
        'dsn'       => 'mongodb://localhost:27017/database1',
    ],

    'othermongodb' =>
    [
        'class'     => '\yii\mongodb\Connection',
        'dsn'       => 'mongodb://localhost:27017/database2',
    ],
    ...
]
```

You can then access your connections with `Yii::$app->mongodb` and `Yii::$app->othermongodb` (or using the `get()`-method if you prefer). This also allows you to specify the correct database for the  ActiveRecord classes that come from a different database:

```
class MyOtherDBMongo extends \yii\mongodb\ActiveRecord
{
   public static function getDb()
   {
       return \Yii::$app->get('othermongodb');
   }
}
```